# Mapping a User, Roles and RolePermissions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following entities:

```
User
Role
```

and then a join table:

```
UsersRoles (UserId, RoleId)
```

and then a RolePermissions table:

```
RolePermissions(Id, RoleId, ....)
```

So on the User entity I want to be able to do:

```
user.Roles
user.RolePermissions
```

My UserMap looks like:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
   public UserMap()
   {

      HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
            .Table("RolesUsers")
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
   }

}
```

Now when I create a new user like:

```
var user = new User { ... };
user.AddRole(new Role { .... } );

UserRepository.Create(user);
```

**It saves the user, and saves the role, but doesn't insert into the RolesUsers table?**

**Also how do I add a property to get all the RolePermissions for a User?**

**Update**

My rolemap has:

```
 HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
            .Table("RolesUsers")
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("UserId")
            .Cascade.All();
```

My unit test actually passes, but I think it is because I don't know how to purge the 1st level cache and it isn't even querying the database with the call for `testUser`:

```
     [Test]
    public void ShouldAddARoleToAUser()
    {
        int userId = -1;
        using (var tx = UserRepository.SessionFactory.OpenSession().BeginTransaction())
        {

            var user = FactoryGirl.GetUser();
            user.AddRole(FactoryGirl.GetRole());

            UserRepository.Create(user);

            tx.Commit();

            UserRepository.SessionFactory.OpenSession().Flush();

            userId = user.Id;
        }

        var testUser = UserRepository.Get(userId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(testUser);
        Assert.IsNotNull(testUser.Roles);
        Assert.IsTrue(testUser.Roles.Count == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(testUser.Roles[0].Id > 0);

    }
```

**Update II**

My user.cs looks like:

```
        private IList<Role> _roles = new List<Role>(); 

        public virtual IList<Role> Roles
        { 
            get { return _roles;  }
        }

        public virtual void AddRole(Role role)
        {
            if(!_roles.Contains(role))
            {
                _roles.Add(role);
            }
        }
```

Role.cs:

```
        private IList<User> _users = new List<User>();
        public virtual IList<User> Users
        {
            get { return _users; }
        }
```

**Update III**

The strange this is my test passes, but looking at profiler I can see that it doesn't even hit sql server so even though I am calling Flush, and then doing a Get(userId) it is loading the entity from memory.  **Also, looking at the other end of the relation (Role), the Role.Users is {} so is that the issue?**

Comment: When you say `Inverse` you're telling NH that the other side of the relationship (Role, in this case) is responsible for saving.  Please post your Role mapping.

Comment: @Brook I added the role map above.

Comment: I really think you just want to remove .Inverse() from the UserMap.  If you were doing Role.Users.Add(user) I think it would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using private backing fields for your collections I think you have to map them like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
   public UserMap()
   {
      HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
                .Table("RolesUsers")
                .Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Inverse();
   }
}
```

Key difference above is `.Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)`

#### Edit:

In addition to this I think you need to simplify your test to something like the following:

```
User newUser = new User();
Role newRole = new Role();
newUser.AddRole(newRole);
newRole.AddUser(newUser);

using (NHibernate.ISession session = iSessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (NHibernate.ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Save(newUser);
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

The above may not be exact but I think you get the idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: strange, it still isn't saving to the RolesUsers table

Comment: What exactly is UserRepository.Create doing?  Is it using the same session as the one you are creating a transaction for?  Is FactoryDb.GetUser() using a session?  What about FactoryDb.GetRole()?  There is a lot of code that we can't see here.  It may help to simplify your test here.  With all the asserts in this test I'm really not sure what you're really trying to test here.  If you are simply trying to test your mappings I would leave all the repositories out of it and use straight NH.

Comment: The repositories all user the same session, which in the tests case are for the current thread (thread_static), on the web side it is per request.

Comment: Is the parentkeycolumn different on the UserMap.cs side versus the RoleMap.cs side? or they should both be the same.

Comment: Yes they are different.  The parent key column on the Roles side is RoleId.

Comment: I updated my question with my User.cs file, it is inserting into User and Role but not UsersRoles.  On my Role.cs side, should I be adding a References User mapping?

Comment: No. You should only have a many to many relationship between `User` and `Role`.  Your mapping for this relationship looks right to me.  I think you just need to come up with another test case that tests this but eliminate all of your repositories and use straight NH.  Take a look at my example above.

Comment: why would I need to add the User to the Role.Users collection?  I only have to add it to one side of the associated not both??

Comment: @codecompleting, The reason I am doing this in the example above is because by default nhibernate does not automagically add this to your `Role.Users` collection unless you re-query a user and their roles in a **NEW** session.  If you re-query it in the same session you used to save your user the `Role.Users` collection will not be right.

Comment: using the raw session helped.

Answer (score 2):

As brook suggests, the `.Inverse()` declaration on the relationship is the reason that UserRole's are not persisted.

taken from the reference of Nhibernate (this is particular to 3.2, but the same exists for earlier versions on NH) http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional
It explicitly says:

"*Changes made only to the inverse end of the association are not persisted*"

And you change the inverse end of the association, `User.Roles` and, of course, is not persisted.

So, you either change your mapping declaration or your code to perform the save on the non-inverse end of the association. The first solution may (or may not) introduce a problem if you have other code that depends on the inverse declaration being on `User.Roles`

side note, you said you don't know to clear the 1st lvl cache, the relevant calls are:

`ISession.Clear()` for a steamroller effect on cache

`ISession.Evict(entity)` for, well, a specific entity

Comment: This is the right answer as to what is the problem.  I would suggest a third solution: modify `User.AddRole` so that it additionally calls `role.Users.Add(this)`, setting both sides of the relationship.

Comment: +1, yes that would work but unfortunately it is hardly elegant :/

Comment: I kept the inverse and it works by adding the user in the call to User.AddRole like @DanielSchilling suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are doing insert in transaction. NHibernate won't insert values in joining table without it